# SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am trying to insert data into an existing table and keep receiving an error.

```
INSERT INTO Patient  
(
  PatientNo,
  PatientFirstName,
  PatientLastName,
  PatientStreetAddress,
  PatientTown,
  PatientCounty,
  PatientPostcode,
  DOB,
  Gender,
  PatientHomeTelephoneNumber,
  PatientMobileTelephoneNumber
)
VALUES 
(
  121, 
  'Miles', 
  'Malone', 
  '64 Zoo Lane', 
  'Clapham', 
  'United Kingdom',
  'SW4 9LP',
  '1989-12-09',
  'M',
  02086950291,
  07498635200
);
```

Error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
INSERT INTO Patient (PatientNo,PatientFirstName,PatientLastName,PatientStreetAddress,PatientTown,PatientCounty,PatientPostcode,DOB,Gender,PatientHomeTelephoneNumber,PatientMobileTelephoneNumber)
VALUES (121, 'Miles', 'Malone', '64 Zoo Lane', 'Clapham', 'United Kingdom','SW4 9LP','1989-12-09','M',02086950291,07498635200)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

Just not sure why this keeps happening I am learning SQL at the moment, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can we see your table structure? I suspect it is the phone numbers that are `VARCHAR2` or something and you're inserting them as `NUMBER`

Comment: @MikeBurton   CREATE TABLE Patient
(
 PatientNo CHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 InvoiceNo CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 PatientFirstName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 PatientLastName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 PatientStreetAddress VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
 PatientTown VARCHAR2(20),
 PatientCounty VARCHAR2(20),
 PatientPostcode VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
 DOB DATE NOT NULL,
 Gender CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT pat_g_nn NOT NULL,
 PatientHomeTelephoneNumber VARCHAR2(11) CONSTRAINT pat_phtn_nn );

Comment: I bet it's the `DOB` column. If that's the case, try using the `TO_DATE` function to parse the date string `'1989-12-09'` properly.

Comment: `PatientHomeTelephoneNumber` is varchar2, you're inserting it as `NUMBER`, it should be surrounded by `''` and I don't see `PatientMobileTelephoneNumber` in your create statement.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Try replacing the string literal for date `'1989-12-09'` with `TO_DATE('1989-12-09','YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: Or since it's in the right format, you could use a date literal as `date '1989-12-09'` instead of using `to_date()`.

Comment: Thanks guys, one more question, if you was to do time eg. appointment time, would you have to put something in front of the time if its formatted as '17:43:09'??

Comment: @alexpoole is it the same way for a time aswell ??

Comment: There's no time data type in Oracle, it'll still be `date` and I think you'll need to include the date part of it as well.

Comment: @LizzyPooh - you can store an appointment date/time as a `DATE`, populating it with `to_date('2014-03-21 09:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`, or `timestamp '2014-03-21 09:15:00.0'` - [read more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#sthref364).

Comment: In general this error happens when we provide a value different to format we have defined in to_date

Comment: @AlexPoole How do you know it's the right format as both month and day are not greater than 12?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost - that's the [ISO date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601); so it's a small assumption but using YYYY-DD-MM would be non-standard and cause great confusion. One of the great advantages of the ISO format is that it is unambiguous. Also the format mask in the answer is YYYY-MM-DD...

Comment: @AlexPoole You should check date format using `SELECT  *  FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS`

Comment: @Alex78191 - the point of the answer using an explicit format mask (or of using a date literal) is that you don't rely on the NLS settings - which the developer can't assume will be the same for whoever runs the code. The original error means the OP's NLS settings didn't match the (apparently ISO) format in the insert anyway. Other answers refer to changing the supplied literal to match NLS settings, but it's still not a good idea to rely on those.

Answer (score 17):

The format you use for the date doesn't match to Oracle's default date format.

A default installation of Oracle Database sets the DEFAULT DATE FORMAT to `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Either use the function `TO_DATE(dateStr, formatStr)` or simply use `dd-MMM-yyyy` date format model.

Comment: The answer is incorrect and misleading. There's no Oracle's default date format. Default date format depends on NLS settings and will vary between sessions for a single Oracle instance. The order of priority: 1. Explicit format in `to_date`. 2. Explicitly set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and `NLS_LANGUAGE`. 3. `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` derived from explicitly set `NLS_TERRITORY`/`NLS_LANGUAGE`. 4. `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` derived from explicitly set `NLS_LANG` environment variable (via values of `NLS_TERRITORY`/`NLS_LANGUAGE` derived from `NLS_LANG`).

Comment: 5. `DD-MON-RR` in English if no above options are set (derived from `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII`, see [Setting Up a Globalization Support Environment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/setting-up-globalization-support-environment.html#GUID-86A29834-AE29-4BA5-8A78-E19C168B690A)).

Answer (score 9):

You can also change the date format for the session.  This is useful, for example, in Perl DBI, where the to_date() function is not available:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD'
```

You can permanently set the default nls_date_format as well:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD'
```

In Perl DBI you can run these commands with the do() method:

```
$db->do("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD');
```

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbi_interface1.htm
https://community.oracle.com/thread/682596?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 8):

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

This happens because you have tried to enter a literal with a format string, but the length of the format string was not the same length as the literal.

You can overcome this issue by carrying out following alteration.

```
TO_DATE('1989-12-09','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

> As a general rule, if you are using the TO_DATE function, TO_TIMESTAMP
>   function, TO_CHAR function, and similar functions, make sure that the
>   literal that you provide matches the format string that you've
>   specified

Answer (score 0):

Use a date literal. Ex. `DATE '1989-12-09'`

Comment: Are you sure that’s valid syntax for Oracle?

Comment: Your answer already appears in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542882/sql-error-ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string-01861/22543299#comment34308577_22543299) (from Alex Poole). I think you could improve your answer if you add a link to the relevant [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) - which does **not** appear in the comment.