# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string : SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date

```
INSERT INTO RENT_CONTRACT VALUES ('123456789','201213','20123444',100,1,' 2014-01-07 ');
```

I'm trying to insert this tuple in my rent_contract table , but this error:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string )

is showing up. Although the type of the last value is `DATE`. Any suggestions for a solution?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I'd think about those extra spaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542882/sql-error-ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string-01861)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle (by default) uses the format DD-MMM-YYYY.  So try this:

```
INSERT INTO RENT_CONTRACT
    VALUES ('123456789', '201213', '20123444', 100,1 , '07-JAN-2014');
```

Also, don't put spaces in string constants.

Or, use the `DATE` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO RENT_CONTRACT
    VALUES ('123456789', '201213', '20123444', 100,1 , DATE '2014-01-07');
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your session NLS settings. What you are looking for is

```
INSERT INTO RENT_CONTRACT VALUES  ('123456789','201213','20123444',100,1,to_date('2014-01-07','yyyy-mm-dd'));
```