# SQL Programming Error. What do I need to do?

Tags: oracle

**Assignment:** Insert 4 rows into emp table

```
Eid, name,  did, hiredate, salary
1,   jeff,  1,   2005-1-1, 70000
2,   susan, 2,   2005-6-1, 50000
3,   bob,   1,   2000-1-1, 90000
4,   steve, 1,   2006-1-1, 60000
```

**My Answer:**

```
INSERT INTO EMP 
VALUES ('1','JEFF','1','2005-01-01',70000);
INSERT INTO EMP
VALUES ('2','SUSAN','2','2005-06-01',50000);
INSERT INTO EMP
VALUES ('3','BOB','1','2000-01-01',90000);
INSERT INTO EMP
VALUES ('4','STEVE','1','2006-01-01',60000);
```

**ERROR:**

```
VALUES ('1','JEFF','1','2005-01-01',70000)
                       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

VALUES ('2','SUSAN','2','2005-06-01',50000)
                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

VALUES ('3','BOB','1','2000-01-01',90000)
                      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

VALUES ('4','STEVE','1','2006-01-01',60000)
                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542882/sql-error-ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string-01861)

Answer (score 0):

For a date constant in the format YYYY-MM-DD, use the `date` indicator:

```
INSERT INTO EMP 
    VALUES ('1', 'JEFF', '1', DATE '2005-01-01', 70000);
```

Note:  if the first and third columns are numbers, then don't use single quotes.

Comment: @JoshKeister - Or use `TO_DATE` - as in `TO_DATE('01-JAN-2005', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`. Share and enjoy.