# SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I keep getting this error in Oracle when i try to run this statement. I am not sure where the formatting error is coming from. maybe someone with fresh eyes can assist me with this problem.

```
INSERT INTO Faculty
(FacNo, FacFirstName, FacLastName, FacCity, FacState,
 FacDept, FacRank, FacSalary, FacSupervisor, FacHireDate, FacZipCode)
 VALUES ('543-21-0987','VICTORIA','EMMANUEL','BOTHELL','WA','MS','PROF',120000.0,'','2001-04-15','98011-2242');
```

Here is the error message i keep getting:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>   01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
>   *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
>              the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
>              "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
>              with no extra whitespace.
>   *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Here are the specs on the table i am trying to INSERT this data into:

> FACNO CHAR(11 BYTE)
>   FACFIRSTNAME    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
>   FACLASTNAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
>   FACCITY VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
>   FACSTATE    CHAR(2 BYTE)
>   FACZIPCODE  CHAR(10 BYTE)
>   FACRANK CHAR(4 BYTE)
>   FACHIREDATE DATE
>   FACSALARY   NUMBER(10,2)
>   FACSUPERVISOR   CHAR(11 BYTE)
>   FACDEPT CHAR(6 BYTE)

Comment: Maybe this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542882/sql-error-ora-01861-literal-does-not-match-format-string-01861

Comment: Use `to_date()` with a format mask, or an ANSI date literal: `date '2001-04-15'`. Details are in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Comment: to_date('2001-04-15','yyyy-mm-dd')

Comment: thank you for your help. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your [`NLS_DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119), the default date format for literals does not match your string.  Never assume dates are formatted one way or another.  use `TO_DATE` function to specify the format, so convert to :

`Insert (... to_date('2001-04-15','YYYY-MM-DD')`...

Answer (score 0):

OldProgrammers answer is the correct answer. Explicitly converting the string to a date is the safest. MS-SQL will generally automatically convert anything recognizable as a date and Oracle will do it if your formatting matches the default formatting for the system. All the oracle systems I have worked with used 'DD/MON/YY' or the two digit day, the three letter month abbreviation and the two digit year as their default and would automatically convert that. Not the proper way to do it but everybody likes to be lazy sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

This happens because you have tried to enter a literal with a format string, but the length of the format string was not the same length as the literal.

You can overcome this issue by carrying out following alteration.

```
TO_DATE('2001-04-15','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

> As a general rule, if you are using the TO_DATE function, TO_TIMESTAMP
>   function, TO_CHAR function, and similar functions, make sure that the
>   literal that you provide matches the format string that you've
>   specified