# I can insert a datetime data

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, ora-01861

```
insert into "PRUEBAS_MÉDICAS" (CÓDIGO, NOMBRE, FECHA_Y_HORA, RESULTADO) 
VALUES('78426', 'TOMOGRAFÍA', '20120618 10:34:09 AM', 'Tumor Abdominal' );
```

And the error is

> Error SQL: ORA-01861: el literal no coincide con la cadena de formato 01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
> *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
> the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
> with no extra whitespace. *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

I want to insert a datetime data

Comment: can you please add the create table of PRUEBAS_MÉDICAS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to insert date and time in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536628/how-to-insert-date-and-time-in-oracle)

Comment: @T.S. Despite what the title says for the question you have linked to, that question is actually an XY-problem as they want to know how to *display* the time component of a `DATE` and the author only thinks that the time component is not being stored because it is not being displayed (it is being stored and the code in their question does work).

Comment: You need to check the documentation for [Datetime Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting error literal does not match format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73169880/i-am-getting-error-literal-does-not-match-format-string)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
insert into "PRUEBAS_MÉDICAS" (CÓDIGO, NOMBRE, FECHA_Y_HORA, RESULTADO)
VALUES('78426', 'TOMOGRAFÍA', TO_DATE ('20120618 10:34:09 AM', 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss am'), 'Tumor Abdominal' );
```

The error is because you haven't specified a date/time format and your default doesn't match what you have used in the values clause.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

1. Use `TO_DATE` and specify a format model:

   ```sql
   insert into "PRUEBAS_MÉDICAS" (
     CÓDIGO,
     NOMBRE,
     FECHA_Y_HORA,
     RESULTADO
   ) VALUES(
     '78426',
     'TOMOGRAFÍA',
     TO_DATE('20120618 10:34:09 AM', 'YYYYMMDD HH12:MI:SS AM'),
     'Tumor Abdominal'
   );
   ```
2. Use a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

   ```sql
   insert into "PRUEBAS_MÉDICAS" (
     CÓDIGO,
     NOMBRE,
     FECHA_Y_HORA,
     RESULTADO
   ) VALUES(
     '78426',
     'TOMOGRAFÍA',
     TIMESTAMP '2012-06-18 10:34:09',
     'Tumor Abdominal'
   );
   ```
3. Use `DATE` and `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` literals:

   ```sql
   insert into "PRUEBAS_MÉDICAS" (
     CÓDIGO,
     NOMBRE,
     FECHA_Y_HORA,
     RESULTADO
   ) VALUES(
     '78426',
     'TOMOGRAFÍA',
     DATE '2012-06-18' + INTERVAL '10:34:09' HOUR TO SECOND,
     'Tumor Abdominal'
   );
   ```
4. Change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`:

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD HH12:MI:SS AM';
   ```

   And use your query and rely on the implicit conversion from string-to-date to work.

   *(Please don't use this last option, either use literals or explicitly specify the conversion using `TO_DATE`).*